# pnpm list all dependencies recursively

Tags: pnpm

I want to list all workspace dependencies recursively for a pnpm package in a workspace.

If I am at the workspace root, and I type:

`pnpm list -r`

I see all dependencies for the whole workspace.  If I type

`pnpm list --prod --filter=@docsndata/endpoints-zapier-connector-impl`

I see only the immediate dependencies for the `@docsndata/endpoints-zapier-connector-impl` package, but my intention was to find all dependencies recursively for only this package.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--depth=Infinity` option:

```
pnpm list --prod --filter=@docsndata/endpoints-zapier-connector-impl --depth=Infinity
```